# How to create Linkedin API by which we can show user data same as repucaution

Tags: linkedin-api

I had create Linked In API as follows instruction from 
http://repucaution.com/installation

User login is working fine,But I am unable to fetch user data same as
http://demo.repucaution.com/social/activity/linkedin . Any body can help what wrong I am doing.....? permission problem or any thing else??